# Why am I not getting setting in kivy?

Tags: kivy

1). Why am I not getting `Settings:` (i.e. no Kivy core settings displayed)  when I click on `setting` button.

2). Where am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

### KV FILE

```
<WindowManager>:
    Hello:
    Setting22:
<Hello>:
    name: 'hello'
    Button:
        text:'setting'
        on_press: root.manager.current="setting22"
<Setting22>:
    name: 'setting22'
    Settings:
```

Comment: Not enough information. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

### [Kivy Settings » add_kivy_panel()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.settings.html#kivy.uix.settings.Settings.add_kivy_panel)

> ```
> add_kivy_panel()
> ```
>
> Add a panel for configuring Kivy. This panel acts directly on the kivy
>   configuration. Feel free to include or exclude it in your
>   configuration.
>
> See [use_kivy_settings()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.use_kivy_settings) for information on enabling/disabling the
>   automatic kivy panel.

## Solution

To display the Kivy core settings in a panel, use `Settings.add_kivy_panel()`

## kv file

- Add `id: settings` for `Settings:` widget
- Add `on_pre_enter` Screen event to invoke `add_kivy_panel()` function

### Snippets - kv

```
<Setting22>:
    name: 'setting22'

    on_pre_enter:
        settings.add_kivy_panel()

    Settings:
        id: settings
```

## Example

In the following example / demo, we are using dynamic classes.

### main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
WindowManager:

<WindowManager@ScreenManager>:
    Hello:
    Setting22:

<Hello@Screen>:
    name: 'hello'
    Button:
        text:'setting'
        on_press: root.manager.current="setting22"

<Setting22@Screen>:
    name: 'setting22'

    on_pre_enter:
        settings.add_kivy_panel()

    Settings:
        id: settings 
"""))
```

## Output

[image: Result]